# Get the value of the dynamic table cell in onclick

Tags: jquery, html-table

If I execute the below jQuery in my code:

```
if (data.PCompany.length > 0) {                        
$.each(data.PCompany, function (i, subEntity) {   
html.push('<tr><td id="row"><a style="color:green;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;" id="link">' + subEntity.Name + '</a></td>
<td id="deem">' + subEntity.Deemed + '</td></tr>'); 
        });
        }
     if (data.CCompany.length > 0) {
    $.each(data.CCompany, function (i, subEntity) {
    html.push('<tr><td nowrap="nowrap">' + subEntity.Name + '</td><td id="deem1" >'
    + subEntity.Deemed +'</td><td>'+ subEntity.Effect shares+ '</td></tr>');
      });            
      }
```

This will produce two tables with many columns in each table..
Now I want to get the value of `subEntity.Deemed` column in both table on click one of the column in my `pcompany` table.
This is having results like:

```
`Pcomapny table`
 <td id="deem">1<td> <td id="deem">2<td>
 Ccompany
 <td id="deem1">3<td> <td id="deem1">4<td> <td id="deem1">5<td> <td id="deem1">6<td>


On first row  onclick of Pcompany table i want to get 1 and 3,
   1 and 4, 1 and 5, 1 and 6
on second row onclick want to get 2 and 3 , 2 and 4, 2 and 5 etc...
```

Comment: Element ID should be unique. You have way too many `td` elements with the ID "deem1".

Comment: Dat is the result of the table.having unique id for first table td as deem and second table td as deem 1